# Add annotations to MKMapView with different images according to location of object

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I've been searching for hours now to find a good tutorial on how to add annotations given a class that holds locations and images of an object (in my case, object is called as EVENT).

Check out what I've done so far, I'm calling this method **setupAnnotations** from viewDidLoad.

```
- (void)setupAnnotations {

    _allEvents = [EventEntity MR_findAll];

    for (EventEntity *event in _allEvents) {

        AVEventAnnotationView *annotation = [[AVEventAnnotationView alloc] initWithOperator:event];

        CLLocation *eventLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[[event latitude] doubleValue] longitude:[[event longitude] doubleValue]];
        annotation.coordinate = eventLocation.coordinate;

        MKPlacemark *eventPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:eventLocation.coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
        MKMapItem *eventItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:eventPlacemark];

        // Im loading image from URL for or based on event object
        UIImageView *imageContainer = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        [imageContainer sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",fullBannerImgPath,[event bannerImg]]]];
        [_bannerImagesArray addObject:imageContainer];

        BOOL hasAnnotation = NO;
        for (AVEventAnnotationView *ann in self.mapView.annotations) {
            if([ann isKindOfClass:[AVEventAnnotationView class]])
            {
                if([[annotation.eventEntity dataId] isEqualToString:[ann.eventEntity dataId]])
                {
                    hasAnnotation = YES;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(!hasAnnotation)
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

And here's my mapview delegate:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapViewIn viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if (mapViewIn != self.mapView || [annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *annotationIdentifier = @"SPGooglePlacesAutocompleteAnnotation";
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationIdentifier];

    // STUCK HERE
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LocationBlue"];
    annotationView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80);
    annotationView.draggable = NO;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```

I'm new to implementing MKMapView. I just read awhile ago the difference between annotation and annotation view.

Anyway, back to my main question or my main problem: How to put annotation/annotationview to mkmapview given I have an array of EVENTS with latitude, longitude and Images?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is AVAnnotationView but I would say you don't need it. You just have to make your Event class conform to MKAnnotation protocol, that is add the property coordinate of type CLLocationCoordinate2D to the Event class. After this just add the events to the map with addAnnotations.

In your mapView:viewForAnnotation: you determine what is the annotation that is being displayed (what is the event that is being displayed) and so you get the image you want to display (you may use tags or any other mean) and set the image for annotation view.

Or you just say something like:

```
if event = annotation as? AVEventAnnotationView { 
//add your image and do stuff
}
```

Comment: wait, I now understand.